# Remove Transaction with a certain ID in Firebase database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I remove the transaction with a certain ID it includes data like name, company, position etc., as shown in the code and image below. It is saved in firebase database and I want a certain transaction completely removed. I cant figure out how to remove I tried `

```
 deleteItem(key){
    const filteredItems = this.state.items.filter(item =>
      item.key!==key);
      this.setState({
        items:filteredItems
    })
  }
```

but its not working

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from '../../config/Fire';
import Transaction from './Transaction/Transaction';

class Tracker extends Component {

    state = {
        transactions: [],

        name: '',
        company: '',
        position: '',
        link: '',
        currentUID: fire.auth().currentUser.uid
    }


    handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState({
            [input]: e.target.value !=="0" ? e.target.value : ""
        });
    }

  
    // add transaction
    addNewTransaction = () => {
        const {name, company, position, link, currentUID} = this.state;
        

        // validation
        if(name && company && position && link){

            const BackUpState = this.state.transactions;
            BackUpState.push({
                id: BackUpState.length + 1,
                name: name,
                company: company,
                position: position,
                link: link,
                user_id: currentUID
            });
            
            fire.database().ref('Transactions/' + currentUID).push({
                id: BackUpState.length,
                name: name,
                company: company,
                position: position,
                link: link,
                user_id: currentUID
            }).then((data) => {
                //success callback
                console.log('success callback');
                this.setState({
                    transactions: BackUpState,
                    name: '',
                    company: '',
                    position: '',
                    link: ''
                })
            }).catch((error)=>{
                //error callback
                console.log('error ' , error)
            });

        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        const {currentUID} = this.state;
        const BackUpState = this.state.transactions;
        fire.database().ref('Transactions/' + currentUID).once('value',
        (snapshot) => {
            // console.log(snapshot);
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                
                BackUpState.push({
                    id: childSnapshot.val().id,
                    name: childSnapshot.val().name,
                    company: childSnapshot.val().company,
                    position: childSnapshot.val().position,
                    link: childSnapshot.val().link,
                    user_id: childSnapshot.val().user_id
                });
                // console.log(childSnapshot.val().name);
            });
            this.setState({
                transactions: BackUpState,
            });
        });
    }

    render(){
        var currentUser = fire.auth().currentUser;
        return(
           
                <div className="newTransactionBlock">
                    <div className="newTransaction">
                        <form>
                            <input
                                onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
                                value={this.state.name}
                                placeholder="Name"
                                type="text"
                                name="name"
                            />
                            <div className="inputGroup">
                                <input
                                    onChange={this.handleChange('company')}
                                    value={this.state.company}
                                    placeholder="Company"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="company"
                                />
                                <input
                                    onChange={this.handleChange('position')}
                                    value={this.state.position}
                                    placeholder="Position"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="position"
                                />
                                <input
                                    onChange={this.handleChange('link')}
                                    value={this.state.link}
                                    placeholder="Link"
                                    type="url"
                                    name="link"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <button onClick={() => this.addNewTransaction()} className="addTransaction">+ Add Transaction</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div className="latestTransactions">
                    <p>Latest Transactions</p>
                    <ul>
                        {
                            Object.keys(this.state.transactions).map((id) => (
                                <Transaction key={id}
                                    name={this.state.transactions[id].name}
                                    company={this.state.transactions[id].company}
                                    position={this.state.transactions[id].position}
                                    link={this.state.transactions[id].link}
                        
                                />
                                
                            ))
                            
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Tracker;
```

[image]

Here is the transaction List imported

```
import React from 'react';


const Transaction = props => {
    return (
        <li>
            <div>{props.name}</div>
            <div>{props.company}</div>
            <div>{props.position}</div>
            <div>{props.link}</div>
            <button>remove</button>
            
        </li>
    );
}

export default Transaction;
```

Comment: To remove a transaction from the JSON you shared, you will need to know at least the UID of the user for who the transaction is, and the `-Mba...` key. If you know those, it should be relatively straightforward to call `remove()` on a reference to that path. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data. Did you try that yet? What happened when you tried? Can you share the code and error?

Comment: Thanks. I'll go and read the docs and try